# How do I include a variable in jquery .html

Tags: jquery, variables

Trying to include a variable in my jquery:

```
var width = $(this).width();
$("#dynamic").html(".dropdown-bottom:before{left:'width'px;}");
```

How do I indicate that width is a variable in the .html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate the strings together:

```
var width = $(this).width();
$("#dynamic").html(".dropdown-bottom:before{left:" + width + "px;}");
```

To subtract from your width, do so before the concatenation:

```
var width = $(this).width() - 20;
```

Since the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/) indicates that width() returns an integer, a simple subtraction should work here. This is of course presuming that **this** is actually referencing the correct thing.

Comment: @rdellara, according to the docs for width, it returns an integer representing the width in pixels. Prior to the concatenation, you'd need to subtract 20 from the width. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out another way
$("#dynamic").html(".dropdown-nav:before{left:" + (width - 20) + "px;}");

Answer (score 1):

by building up the string by using the variable:

```
$("#dynamic").html(".dropdown-bottom:before{left:" + width + "px;}");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dynamic").html(".dropdown-bottom:before{left:" + width + "px;}");
```